# What is the best practice for modifying a part of a base class for one-time usage?

Tags: python

For context, I'm making a framework for creating RSS feeds from arbitrary pages. The way it works is I have a base class with a lot of setup and want to plug in generators that describe items being returned; then I create one instance of this class. I can think of two ways to do this:

1) Make a derived class that overrides all relevant properties and methods and then create an instance of it:

```
class Base:

    property = None

    def customizable_function(self, many, different, arguments):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __init__(self):
        non_customizable_preparation()
        customizable_function(1, 2, 3)

class Derived:

    property = "useful"

    def customizable_function(self, many, different, arguments):
        do_stuff()

Derived()
```

2) Don't create a second class, make the init function take all relevant arguments:

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self, customizable_function, property):
        non_customizable_preparation()
        customizable_function(1, 2, 3)

def function_that_will_be_passed(self, many, different, arguments):
    do_stuff()

Base(function_that_will_be_passed, property="useful")
```

The second approach seems cleaner, but in it `customizable_function` has to be defined outside of a class, while having its signature match what is expected. Is there some non-obvious concern which makes one of those approaches significantly better? Or is this whole thing a bad idea and I should do everything differently?

Comment: I don't see why you think the first approach is worse.  It is the standard way (maybe with a `raise NotImplementedError()` in the default implementation of `customizable_function()`, to have an early and explicitly clear fail in case a subclass has forgotten overriding this method).

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing in code, I just forgot it in the example. I'll add it.

Comment: I suggest to implement ``BASE`` as an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) and mark ``customizable_function`` as an [abstract method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod). In this way you have a number of advantages: 1) the interpreter forces you to reimplement ``customizable_function`` and you don't risk to get an ``NotImplementedError`` in a random place of the code; 2) you can have some boilerplate code in the original method that can be used with ``super``

Comment: Excellent tip, thanks.